# Backtrace on ARM has repeating entries

Tags: c++, c, linux, arm, backtrace

I experience a strange behaviour when creating a backtrace on an ARM platform running under Linux. Sometimes the backtrace output seems to be corrupted, depending on the code executed prior to the fault.

Here's my `Crash.cpp` code:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <execinfo.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/syscall.h>
#include <ucontext.h>

const unsigned int CRASH_MAX_BACKTRACE_DEPTH = 30u;
void * crashData[CRASH_MAX_BACKTRACE_DEPTH] = { 0 };

void sigHandler(int signum, siginfo_t * siginfo, void * context)
{
    int numFrames = backtrace(crashData, CRASH_MAX_BACKTRACE_DEPTH);

    // restore faulting address
#if defined(__i386__)
    crashData[2] = (void *)(((ucontext_t *)context)->uc_mcontext.gregs[REG_EIP]);
#elif defined(__arm__)
    crashData[2] = (void *)(((ucontext_t *)context)->uc_mcontext.arm_pc);
#else
#error "Unsupported platform."
#endif

    char ** symbols = backtrace_symbols(crashData, numFrames);

    for (int i = 0; i < numFrames; i++)
    {
        printf("%d: %s\n", i, symbols[i]);
    }

    // resend the signal to the default handler in order to produce a core dump
    (void) signal(signum, SIG_DFL);
    (void) kill(syscall(__NR_gettid), signum);
}

void three()
{
    char str[1];
    printf("%s\n", "foo");

    // produce SIGSEGV
    int * p = 0;
    *p = 1;
}

void two()
{
    three();
}

void one()
{
    two();
}

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    struct sigaction action;
    sigemptyset(&action.sa_mask);
    action.sa_sigaction = &sigHandler;
    action.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO;   // we want the 3rd parameter of the handler to be the siginfo_t additional data
    sigaction(SIGSEGV, &action, 0);

    one();

    return 0;
}
```

I cross-compiled it on a X86/Linux like that:

```
 /path-to-cross-gcc/g++ -g3 -O0 Crash.cpp -o Crash -funwind-tables -rdynamic
```

When I run this, it gives me:

```
root@armbox:/# ./Crash
foo
0: ./Crash(_Z10sigHandleriP9siginfo_tPv+0x24) [0x8a3c]
1: /lib/libc.so.6(__default_rt_sa_restorer_v2+0) [0x76c56110]
2: ./Crash(_Z5threev+0x24) [0x8b1c]
3: ./Crash(_Z5threev+0x24) [0x8b1c]
4: ./Crash(_Z5threev+0x24) [0x8b1c]
5: ./Crash(_Z5threev+0x24) [0x8b1c]
6: ./Crash(_Z5threev+0x24) [0x8b1c]
7: ./Crash(_Z5threev+0x24) [0x8b1c]
8: ./Crash(_Z5threev+0x24) [0x8b1c]
9: ./Crash(_Z5threev+0x24) [0x8b1c]
10: ./Crash(_Z5threev+0x24) [0x8b1c]
11: ./Crash(_Z5threev+0x24) [0x8b1c]
12: ./Crash(_Z5threev+0x24) [0x8b1c]
13: ./Crash(_Z5threev+0x24) [0x8b1c]
14: ./Crash(_Z5threev+0x24) [0x8b1c]
15: ./Crash(_Z5threev+0x24) [0x8b1c]
16: ./Crash(_Z5threev+0x24) [0x8b1c]
17: ./Crash(_Z5threev+0x24) [0x8b1c]
18: ./Crash(_Z5threev+0x24) [0x8b1c]
19: ./Crash(_Z5threev+0x24) [0x8b1c]
20: ./Crash(_Z5threev+0x24) [0x8b1c]
21: ./Crash(_Z5threev+0x24) [0x8b1c]
22: ./Crash(_Z5threev+0x24) [0x8b1c]
23: ./Crash(_Z5threev+0x24) [0x8b1c]
24: ./Crash(_Z5threev+0x24) [0x8b1c]
25: ./Crash(_Z5threev+0x24) [0x8b1c]
26: ./Crash(_Z5threev+0x24) [0x8b1c]
27: ./Crash(_Z5threev+0x24) [0x8b1c]
28: ./Crash(_Z5threev+0x24) [0x8b1c]
29: ./Crash(_Z5threev+0x24) [0x8b1c]
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

The stack looks corrupted, from the 3rd frame on the faulting address is just repeated. However, if I make a core analysis, the stack seems to be fine:

```
root@armbox:/# gdb Crash Crash.core 
GNU gdb (GDB) 7.4.1
Copyright (C) 2012 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "arm-oe-linux-gnueabi".
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>...
Reading symbols from /jci/blackforest/Crash...done.
[New LWP 32356]
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/libthread_db.so.1".
Core was generated by `./Crash'.
Program terminated with signal 11, Segmentation fault.
#0  0x00008b1c in three () at Crash.cpp:43
43          *p = 1;
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00008b1c in three () at Crash.cpp:43
#1  0x00008b40 in two () at Crash.cpp:48
#2  0x00008b50 in one () at Crash.cpp:53
#3  0x00008ba0 in main (argc=1, argv=0x7ef12b94) at Crash.cpp:64
```

Now here's the really interesting part. If I change the line `char str[1];` in the faulting function `three()` to `char str;`, then the backtrace is flawless:

```
root@armbox:/# ./Crash
foo
0: ./Crash(_Z10sigHandleriP9siginfo_tPv+0x24) [0x8a3c]
1: /lib/libc.so.6(__default_rt_sa_restorer_v2+0) [0x76c3a110]
2: ./Crash(_Z5threev+0x24) [0x8b1c]
3: ./Crash(_Z3twov+0xc) [0x8b38]
4: ./Crash(_Z3onev+0xc) [0x8b48]
5: ./Crash(main+0x4c) [0x8b98]
6: /lib/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0x114) [0x76c23e1c]
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

The gdb core backtrace is the same. This is also true if I just remove the line `printf("%s\n", "foo");` and let `char str[1];` in place. For some reason the combination of the two is affecting the stack in a way that `backtrace()` fails to get a proper result. Interestingly enough this only happens on ARM/Linux, on X86/Linux it all works fine.

I know about the fact, that calling `backtrace_symbols()` and `printf()` in a signal handler is a very bad idea. However, this is just a showcase and I experienced the problem first within a software that uses `backtrace_symbols_fd()` to write the data into a file. So this should not be the issue here.

I'm using libc version 2.16. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: Here's the output of `objdump -d Crash`:

```
Crash:     file format elf32-littlearm


Disassembly of section .init:

0000881c <_init>:
    881c:   e92d4008    push    {r3, lr}
    8820:   eb00003e    bl  8920 <call_weak_fn>
    8824:   e8bd8008    pop {r3, pc}

Disassembly of section .plt:

00008828 <.plt>:
    8828:   e52de004    push    {lr}        ; (str lr, [sp, #-4]!)
    882c:   e59fe004    ldr lr, [pc, #4]    ; 8838 <_init+0x1c>
    8830:   e08fe00e    add lr, pc, lr
    8834:   e5bef008    ldr pc, [lr, #8]!
    8838:   000085a4    .word   0x000085a4
    883c:   e28fc600    add ip, pc, #0
    8840:   e28cca08    add ip, ip, #32768  ; 0x8000
    8844:   e5bcf5a4    ldr pc, [ip, #1444]!    ; 0x5a4
    8848:   e28fc600    add ip, pc, #0
    884c:   e28cca08    add ip, ip, #32768  ; 0x8000
    8850:   e5bcf59c    ldr pc, [ip, #1436]!    ; 0x59c
    8854:   e28fc600    add ip, pc, #0
    8858:   e28cca08    add ip, ip, #32768  ; 0x8000
    885c:   e5bcf594    ldr pc, [ip, #1428]!    ; 0x594
    8860:   e28fc600    add ip, pc, #0
    8864:   e28cca08    add ip, ip, #32768  ; 0x8000
    8868:   e5bcf58c    ldr pc, [ip, #1420]!    ; 0x58c
    886c:   e28fc600    add ip, pc, #0
    8870:   e28cca08    add ip, ip, #32768  ; 0x8000
    8874:   e5bcf584    ldr pc, [ip, #1412]!    ; 0x584
    8878:   e28fc600    add ip, pc, #0
    887c:   e28cca08    add ip, ip, #32768  ; 0x8000
    8880:   e5bcf57c    ldr pc, [ip, #1404]!    ; 0x57c
    8884:   e28fc600    add ip, pc, #0
    8888:   e28cca08    add ip, ip, #32768  ; 0x8000
    888c:   e5bcf574    ldr pc, [ip, #1396]!    ; 0x574
    8890:   e28fc600    add ip, pc, #0
    8894:   e28cca08    add ip, ip, #32768  ; 0x8000
    8898:   e5bcf56c    ldr pc, [ip, #1388]!    ; 0x56c
    889c:   e28fc600    add ip, pc, #0
    88a0:   e28cca08    add ip, ip, #32768  ; 0x8000
    88a4:   e5bcf564    ldr pc, [ip, #1380]!    ; 0x564
    88a8:   e28fc600    add ip, pc, #0
    88ac:   e28cca08    add ip, ip, #32768  ; 0x8000
    88b0:   e5bcf55c    ldr pc, [ip, #1372]!    ; 0x55c
    88b4:   e28fc600    add ip, pc, #0
    88b8:   e28cca08    add ip, ip, #32768  ; 0x8000
    88bc:   e5bcf554    ldr pc, [ip, #1364]!    ; 0x554
    88c0:   e28fc600    add ip, pc, #0
    88c4:   e28cca08    add ip, ip, #32768  ; 0x8000
    88c8:   e5bcf54c    ldr pc, [ip, #1356]!    ; 0x54c
    88cc:   e28fc600    add ip, pc, #0
    88d0:   e28cca08    add ip, ip, #32768  ; 0x8000
    88d4:   e5bcf544    ldr pc, [ip, #1348]!    ; 0x544
    88d8:   e28fc600    add ip, pc, #0
    88dc:   e28cca08    add ip, ip, #32768  ; 0x8000
    88e0:   e5bcf53c    ldr pc, [ip, #1340]!    ; 0x53c

Disassembly of section .text:

000088e4 <_start>:
    88e4:   e3a0b000    mov fp, #0
    88e8:   e3a0e000    mov lr, #0
    88ec:   e49d1004    pop {r1}        ; (ldr r1, [sp], #4)
    88f0:   e1a0200d    mov r2, sp
    88f4:   e52d2004    push    {r2}        ; (str r2, [sp, #-4]!)
    88f8:   e52d0004    push    {r0}        ; (str r0, [sp, #-4]!)
    88fc:   e59fc010    ldr ip, [pc, #16]   ; 8914 <_start+0x30>
    8900:   e52dc004    push    {ip}        ; (str ip, [sp, #-4]!)
    8904:   e59f000c    ldr r0, [pc, #12]   ; 8918 <_start+0x34>
    8908:   e59f300c    ldr r3, [pc, #12]   ; 891c <_start+0x38>
    890c:   ebffffd0    bl  8854 <_init+0x38>
    8910:   ebffffcc    bl  8848 <_init+0x2c>
    8914:   00008c20    .word   0x00008c20
    8918:   00008b54    .word   0x00008b54
    891c:   00008bbc    .word   0x00008bbc

00008920 <call_weak_fn>:
    8920:   e59f3014    ldr r3, [pc, #20]   ; 893c <call_weak_fn+0x1c>
    8924:   e59f2014    ldr r2, [pc, #20]   ; 8940 <call_weak_fn+0x20>
    8928:   e08f3003    add r3, pc, r3
    892c:   e7932002    ldr r2, [r3, r2]
    8930:   e3520000    cmp r2, #0
    8934:   012fff1e    bxeq    lr
    8938:   eaffffcb    b   886c <_init+0x50>
    893c:   000084ac    .word   0x000084ac
    8940:   00000044    .word   0x00000044

00008944 <deregister_tm_clones>:
    8944:   e92d4008    push    {r3, lr}
    8948:   e59f0020    ldr r0, [pc, #32]   ; 8970 <deregister_tm_clones+0x2c>
    894c:   e59f3020    ldr r3, [pc, #32]   ; 8974 <deregister_tm_clones+0x30>
    8950:   e0603003    rsb r3, r0, r3
    8954:   e3530006    cmp r3, #6
    8958:   98bd8008    popls   {r3, pc}
    895c:   e59f3014    ldr r3, [pc, #20]   ; 8978 <deregister_tm_clones+0x34>
    8960:   e3530000    cmp r3, #0
    8964:   08bd8008    popeq   {r3, pc}
    8968:   e12fff33    blx r3
    896c:   e8bd8008    pop {r3, pc}
    8970:   00010e2c    .word   0x00010e2c
    8974:   00010e2f    .word   0x00010e2f
    8978:   00000000    .word   0x00000000

0000897c <register_tm_clones>:
    897c:   e59f002c    ldr r0, [pc, #44]   ; 89b0 <register_tm_clones+0x34>
    8980:   e59f102c    ldr r1, [pc, #44]   ; 89b4 <register_tm_clones+0x38>
    8984:   e92d4008    push    {r3, lr}
    8988:   e0601001    rsb r1, r0, r1
    898c:   e1a01141    asr r1, r1, #2
    8990:   e0811fa1    add r1, r1, r1, lsr #31
    8994:   e1b010c1    asrs    r1, r1, #1
    8998:   08bd8008    popeq   {r3, pc}
    899c:   e59f3014    ldr r3, [pc, #20]   ; 89b8 <register_tm_clones+0x3c>
    89a0:   e3530000    cmp r3, #0
    89a4:   08bd8008    popeq   {r3, pc}
    89a8:   e12fff33    blx r3
    89ac:   e8bd8008    pop {r3, pc}
    89b0:   00010e2c    .word   0x00010e2c
    89b4:   00010e2c    .word   0x00010e2c
    89b8:   00000000    .word   0x00000000

000089bc <__do_global_dtors_aux>:
    89bc:   e92d4010    push    {r4, lr}
    89c0:   e59f4018    ldr r4, [pc, #24]   ; 89e0 <__do_global_dtors_aux+0x24>
    89c4:   e5d43000    ldrb    r3, [r4]
    89c8:   e3530000    cmp r3, #0
    89cc:   18bd8010    popne   {r4, pc}
    89d0:   ebffffdb    bl  8944 <deregister_tm_clones>
    89d4:   e3a03001    mov r3, #1
    89d8:   e5c43000    strb    r3, [r4]
    89dc:   e8bd8010    pop {r4, pc}
    89e0:   00010e2c    .word   0x00010e2c

000089e4 <frame_dummy>:
    89e4:   e59f0024    ldr r0, [pc, #36]   ; 8a10 <frame_dummy+0x2c>
    89e8:   e92d4008    push    {r3, lr}
    89ec:   e5903000    ldr r3, [r0]
    89f0:   e3530000    cmp r3, #0
    89f4:   0a000003    beq 8a08 <frame_dummy+0x24>
    89f8:   e59f3014    ldr r3, [pc, #20]   ; 8a14 <frame_dummy+0x30>
    89fc:   e3530000    cmp r3, #0
    8a00:   0a000000    beq 8a08 <frame_dummy+0x24>
    8a04:   e12fff33    blx r3
    8a08:   e8bd4008    pop {r3, lr}
    8a0c:   eaffffda    b   897c <register_tm_clones>
    8a10:   00010cd8    .word   0x00010cd8
    8a14:   00000000    .word   0x00000000

00008a18 <_Z10sigHandleriP9siginfo_tPv>:
    8a18:   e92d4800    push    {fp, lr}
    8a1c:   e28db004    add fp, sp, #4
    8a20:   e24dd020    sub sp, sp, #32
    8a24:   e50b0018    str r0, [fp, #-24]
    8a28:   e50b101c    str r1, [fp, #-28]
    8a2c:   e50b2020    str r2, [fp, #-32]
    8a30:   e59f00b8    ldr r0, [pc, #184]  ; 8af0 <_Z10sigHandleriP9siginfo_tPv+0xd8>
    8a34:   e3a0101e    mov r1, #30
    8a38:   ebffff94    bl  8890 <_init+0x74>
    8a3c:   e1a03000    mov r3, r0
    8a40:   e50b300c    str r3, [fp, #-12]
    8a44:   e51b3020    ldr r3, [fp, #-32]
    8a48:   e593305c    ldr r3, [r3, #92]   ; 0x5c
    8a4c:   e1a02003    mov r2, r3
    8a50:   e59f3098    ldr r3, [pc, #152]  ; 8af0 <_Z10sigHandleriP9siginfo_tPv+0xd8>
    8a54:   e5832008    str r2, [r3, #8]
    8a58:   e59f0090    ldr r0, [pc, #144]  ; 8af0 <_Z10sigHandleriP9siginfo_tPv+0xd8>
    8a5c:   e51b100c    ldr r1, [fp, #-12]
    8a60:   ebffff87    bl  8884 <_init+0x68>
    8a64:   e50b0010    str r0, [fp, #-16]
    8a68:   e3a03000    mov r3, #0
    8a6c:   e50b3008    str r3, [fp, #-8]
    8a70:   ea00000b    b   8aa4 <_Z10sigHandleriP9siginfo_tPv+0x8c>
    8a74:   e51b3008    ldr r3, [fp, #-8]
    8a78:   e1a03103    lsl r3, r3, #2
    8a7c:   e51b2010    ldr r2, [fp, #-16]
    8a80:   e0823003    add r3, r2, r3
    8a84:   e5933000    ldr r3, [r3]
    8a88:   e59f0064    ldr r0, [pc, #100]  ; 8af4 <_Z10sigHandleriP9siginfo_tPv+0xdc>
    8a8c:   e51b1008    ldr r1, [fp, #-8]
    8a90:   e1a02003    mov r2, r3
    8a94:   ebffff80    bl  889c <_init+0x80>
    8a98:   e51b3008    ldr r3, [fp, #-8]
    8a9c:   e2833001    add r3, r3, #1
    8aa0:   e50b3008    str r3, [fp, #-8]
    8aa4:   e51b2008    ldr r2, [fp, #-8]
    8aa8:   e51b300c    ldr r3, [fp, #-12]
    8aac:   e1520003    cmp r2, r3
    8ab0:   a3a03000    movge   r3, #0
    8ab4:   b3a03001    movlt   r3, #1
    8ab8:   e20330ff    and r3, r3, #255    ; 0xff
    8abc:   e3530000    cmp r3, #0
    8ac0:   1affffeb    bne 8a74 <_Z10sigHandleriP9siginfo_tPv+0x5c>
    8ac4:   e51b0018    ldr r0, [fp, #-24]
    8ac8:   e3a01000    mov r1, #0
    8acc:   ebffff63    bl  8860 <_init+0x44>
    8ad0:   e3a000e0    mov r0, #224    ; 0xe0
    8ad4:   ebffff7f    bl  88d8 <_init+0xbc>
    8ad8:   e1a03000    mov r3, r0
    8adc:   e1a00003    mov r0, r3
    8ae0:   e51b1018    ldr r1, [fp, #-24]
    8ae4:   ebffff75    bl  88c0 <_init+0xa4>
    8ae8:   e24bd004    sub sp, fp, #4
    8aec:   e8bd8800    pop {fp, pc}
    8af0:   00010e30    .word   0x00010e30
    8af4:   00008c30    .word   0x00008c30

00008af8 <_Z5threev>:
    8af8:   e92d4800    push    {fp, lr}
    8afc:   e28db004    add fp, sp, #4
    8b00:   e24dd008    sub sp, sp, #8
    8b04:   e59f0024    ldr r0, [pc, #36]   ; 8b30 <_Z5threev+0x38>
    8b08:   ebffff69    bl  88b4 <_init+0x98>
    8b0c:   e3a03000    mov r3, #0
    8b10:   e50b3008    str r3, [fp, #-8]
    8b14:   e51b3008    ldr r3, [fp, #-8]
    8b18:   e3a02001    mov r2, #1
    8b1c:   e5832000    str r2, [r3]
    8b20:   ea000000    b   8b28 <_Z5threev+0x30>
    8b24:   ebffff53    bl  8878 <_init+0x5c>
    8b28:   e24bd004    sub sp, fp, #4
    8b2c:   e8bd8800    pop {fp, pc}
    8b30:   00008c38    .word   0x00008c38

00008b34 <_Z3twov>:
    8b34:   e92d4800    push    {fp, lr}
    8b38:   e28db004    add fp, sp, #4
    8b3c:   ebffffed    bl  8af8 <_Z5threev>
    8b40:   e8bd8800    pop {fp, pc}

00008b44 <_Z3onev>:
    8b44:   e92d4800    push    {fp, lr}
    8b48:   e28db004    add fp, sp, #4
    8b4c:   ebfffff8    bl  8b34 <_Z3twov>
    8b50:   e8bd8800    pop {fp, pc}

00008b54 <main>:
    8b54:   e92d4800    push    {fp, lr}
    8b58:   e28db004    add fp, sp, #4
    8b5c:   e24dd098    sub sp, sp, #152    ; 0x98
    8b60:   e50b0098    str r0, [fp, #-152] ; 0x98
    8b64:   e50b109c    str r1, [fp, #-156] ; 0x9c
    8b68:   e24b3090    sub r3, fp, #144    ; 0x90
    8b6c:   e2833004    add r3, r3, #4
    8b70:   e1a00003    mov r0, r3
    8b74:   ebffff30    bl  883c <_init+0x20>
    8b78:   e59f3038    ldr r3, [pc, #56]   ; 8bb8 <main+0x64>
    8b7c:   e50b3090    str r3, [fp, #-144] ; 0x90
    8b80:   e3a03004    mov r3, #4
    8b84:   e50b300c    str r3, [fp, #-12]
    8b88:   e24b3090    sub r3, fp, #144    ; 0x90
    8b8c:   e3a0000b    mov r0, #11
    8b90:   e1a01003    mov r1, r3
    8b94:   e3a02000    mov r2, #0
    8b98:   ebffff42    bl  88a8 <_init+0x8c>
    8b9c:   ebffffe8    bl  8b44 <_Z3onev>
    8ba0:   e3a03000    mov r3, #0
    8ba4:   ea000000    b   8bac <main+0x58>
    8ba8:   ebffff32    bl  8878 <_init+0x5c>
    8bac:   e1a00003    mov r0, r3
    8bb0:   e24bd004    sub sp, fp, #4
    8bb4:   e8bd8800    pop {fp, pc}
    8bb8:   00008a18    .word   0x00008a18

00008bbc <__libc_csu_init>:
    8bbc:   e92d45f8    push    {r3, r4, r5, r6, r7, r8, sl, lr}
    8bc0:   e1a07000    mov r7, r0
    8bc4:   e59f604c    ldr r6, [pc, #76]   ; 8c18 <__libc_csu_init+0x5c>
    8bc8:   e1a08001    mov r8, r1
    8bcc:   e59f5048    ldr r5, [pc, #72]   ; 8c1c <__libc_csu_init+0x60>
    8bd0:   e1a0a002    mov sl, r2
    8bd4:   e08f6006    add r6, pc, r6
    8bd8:   ebffff0f    bl  881c <_init>
    8bdc:   e08f5005    add r5, pc, r5
    8be0:   e0656006    rsb r6, r5, r6
    8be4:   e1b06146    asrs    r6, r6, #2
    8be8:   08bd85f8    popeq   {r3, r4, r5, r6, r7, r8, sl, pc}
    8bec:   e2455004    sub r5, r5, #4
    8bf0:   e3a04000    mov r4, #0
    8bf4:   e2844001    add r4, r4, #1
    8bf8:   e5b53004    ldr r3, [r5, #4]!
    8bfc:   e1a00007    mov r0, r7
    8c00:   e1a01008    mov r1, r8
    8c04:   e1a0200a    mov r2, sl
    8c08:   e12fff33    blx r3
    8c0c:   e1540006    cmp r4, r6
    8c10:   1afffff7    bne 8bf4 <__libc_csu_init+0x38>
    8c14:   e8bd85f8    pop {r3, r4, r5, r6, r7, r8, sl, pc}
    8c18:   000080f8    .word   0x000080f8
    8c1c:   000080ec    .word   0x000080ec

00008c20 <__libc_csu_fini>:
    8c20:   e12fff1e    bx  lr

Disassembly of section .fini:

00008c24 <_fini>:
    8c24:   e92d4008    push    {r3, lr}
    8c28:   e8bd8008    pop {r3, pc}
```

Comment: Did you try `-fno-omit-frame-pointer`?

Comment: also try to add assembly by either dis in gdb, or with objdump.

Comment: @auselen: `-fno-omit-frame-pointer` had no effect. I updated the question with the output of objdump but I can't make head or tail of it.

Comment: @artlessnoise: Replacing the `signal` and `kill` calls with `_exit(-1)` didn't have any effect. I also checked `ucontext_t` on the target and the cross-GCC installation and yes, they match.

Comment: What happens if you omit the `crashData[2]` lines (with `char str[1];`)?  Also printout `numFrames`, to see which one is creating the extra *frames*.  Is the origin `backtrace()` or `backtrace_symbols()`?

Comment: @artlessnoise: If I just do a `int numFrames = backtrace(crashData, CRASH_MAX_BACKTRACE_DEPTH);` followed by a `for (int i=0; i<numFrames; i++) { printf("%d: %p\n", i, crashData[i]); }` I still see 30 frames with the addresses repeating from the 3rd entry on. So the return value of `backtrace` itself seems to be corrupt. But what I can I do about that?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this may have been reported and fixed [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=56846).  I don't see a workaround other than recompiling libstdc++ with the recent patch.  I observe the same behaviour with gcc 4.6.1 and libstdc++ 3.4.16.